# Gerar Excel com query php

Tags: php, microsoft-excel, mysql

Necessito de uma ajuda.
Tenho uma query em php e Mysql e gostaria de acrescentar a essa query a opção de exportar os dados também para excel. 
É possivel fazer isso com o php?

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Informação</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-4">Trabalhadores</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Credenciais</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Equipamentos</a></li>
</ul>
<?php

 include("conectar.php");

$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "select * from TABELAS   Where CAMPOS and tb_trabalhador.id = $id order by tb_trabalhador.id asc ";
$qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
//Todos os dados a serem mostrado
```

Comment: http://sdevlab.wordpress.com/2010/06/01/php-como-criar-e-exportar-planilhas-do-excel-com-dados-de-um-bd/ Nesse link mostra bem certinho!

Answer (score 5):

Sim, é possível. Uma possibilidade é criar um botão para exportar, quando o usuário clicar nesse botão vc irá ter que formar a sua tabela html da mesma forma que esta gerando para a visualização mas tem que configurar o header para fazer o download do excel.

Por exemplo:

```
$html = "<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Coluna 1</td>        
        <td>Coluna 2</td>        
        <td>Coluna 2</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Coluna 1</td>        
        <td>Coluna 2</td>        
        <td>Coluna 2</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Coluna 1</td>        
        <td>Coluna 2</td>        
        <td>Coluna 2</td>        
    </tr>
</table>";

// Configurações header para forçar o download
header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"nome_arquivo.xls\"" );
header ("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );

echo $html;
```

Answer (score 3):

É possível, uma das alternativas é utilizar a lib [phpexcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) para a manipulação de arquivos dos excel

```
include '../../includes/excel/PHPExcel.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A1', 'Nome');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B1', 'Idade');

$linha=2;
foreach ($dadosDoBanco as $item){
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A'.$linha, $item['nome']);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$linha, $item['idade']);
    $linha++;
}

//formata o cabeçalho
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="lista.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');


$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Também é possível atribuir valores as celulas utilizando o método `setCellValueByColumnAndRow('coluna', 'linha', 'valor')`, indicado para trabalhar com número varíavel de colunas/valores.

Answer (score 1):

**Existem algumas formas**

1. Forçar o header para o navegador salvar com a extensão. Embora seja um `html` com outra extensão o excel aceita carregar, da forma que esta, sem formatação se usar css externos / imagens sem endereço completo do site. Neste procedimento ele identifica as colunas das `tables` do `HTML` como celulas.

   `<?php header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
   header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"nome_arquivo.xls\"" ); ?>`
2. Usar um *[OpenXML](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Open-XML-Formats-and-file-name-extensions-5200d93c-3449-4380-8e11-31ef14555b18)*, esse gerado mais facilmente pelo [PHP Excel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel).
   A diferença é que o *OpenXML* replica o formato correto de arquivo do Excel, tanto no `.XLS`, tal como `.XLSX`. Um arquivo gerado pelo excel é um *OpenXML* gerado e criptografado, assim como imagens a ele anexadas são convertidas para *Base64*. No site do *PHP Excel* ao efetuar o download já vem com vários exemplos. basta extrai-los e executa-los

***Exemplo de OpenXML retirado do site da Microsoft***
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]